# Tomcat Data Source Losing Connection With DB

Tags: java, tomcat, connection, datasource, firewall

I need a solution about tomcat datasource configuration.
I have 2 nginx front of my tomcats.These are feeding my app, these are Webservice.
Tomcat machines and database are in different ip blog so its going firewall in each request.
When i started my tomcats everythigs well.But for example after 10 hour our after 20 hour later everythings going bad.That tomcats can not set connection.All service down.I share my datasource file and hope you find some solution or some other suggestions other than datasource file.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   ----
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

```
    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <props merge="default">
            <prop key="v$session.program">ws_${server}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <props merge="default">
            <prop key="MinLimit">1</prop>
            <prop key="MaxLimit">120</prop>
            <prop key="InitialLimit">5</prop>
            <prop key="MaxStatementsLimit">50</prop>                
            <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">30</prop>
            <prop key="InactivityTimeout">600</prop>
            <prop key="AbandonedConnectionTimeout">180</prop>
            <prop key="PropertyCheckInterval">300</prop>                
            <prop key="ValidateConnection">true</prop>  
            <prop key="TimeToLiveTimeout">600</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.ws.oracle.pool.JndiExporter">
    <property name="bean" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="dsName" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You didn't give the connection cache a validation query, e.g. `SELECT 1` (or `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` if using Oracle). How would cache know if connection has timed out, or was otherwise disconnected?

Comment: can you open it more please andreas ? 
Do i have to add one more property to data source about cache validation ?